# Comparing Resultsets In java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am looking for ways to compare two `ResultSet`s in java (`RS1` and `RS2`).

**Things to note/Requirements**

- The results sets are from two different databases(`Oracle` & `SQl-Server`).Thus I can't make any sql  query changes to copare the results fetched.
- Any of the `ResultSet`s can have more rows than each other.
- Any of the `ResultSet` can have data that is not their in the other `ResultSet`

**Example:**

```
RS1                        RS2
Column1 Column2            Column1 Column2 Column3
A       1                  A       2       ITEM1
C       1                  B       4       ITEM2
D       2                  C       2       ITEM3
E       5                  D       1       ITEM4
```

**Expected Result**

==> A is valid , because it is in `RS1` & `RS2`, also `Column2` for A in RS2 > `Column2` for A in RS1

==> B is invalid, as it is not there in RS1

==> C is valid , because it is in `RS1` & `RS2`, also `Column2` for C in RS2  > `Column2` for C in RS1

==> D is invalid , because even though it is there in `RS1` and `RS2`,the `Column2` for D in RS2 < `Column2` for D in RS1

==> E is invalid because it is not there in `RS2`

Looking for possible options to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Traverse through both your `ResultSet`s and store them in a `Map<String, Integer>`. After that you can traverse through either of the `keySet` and keep comparing the `values`.

This lets you compare 2 `ResultSet`s from any kind of DB(`Oracle, MySql, SQLServer, etc.`).

Comment: @RJ Apologies mate Map only works on key , value pair. One of my RS has 3 values. Apologies , didn't mention that initially while asking the query as I didn't think that would make any difference :(

Comment: @misguided - you're right. That doesn't make a difference even now. You shouldn't be worried about `column3` as you won't be putting that in your map, and nor in your checks. Let the `ResultSet` return 3 columns, you just need to pick column 1 & 2 from it to populate your `Map` anyways.

Comment: @RJ what do I do if I want to print column3 for RS2 items not there in RS1?

Comment: Then how about using a double `Map`? Please don't tell later that you've another column. `Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>`, column1, column2, column in order. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply read the results into two Maps with key as the primary key which seems to be Column1 in your case, the value is Column2.

Then you can iterate through the entry set of the first map and see if the second map has the key and if so, compare the values.

Comment: Mate one of the RS has 3 values , apologies forgot to mention that in the initial query. Have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read the values from each ResultSet, and put it in List and then
compare the two Lists. 
You can perform `getMetaData` on each resultset in order to get information on the columns. 
This will include information like the number of the columns, and then you will be able to write a simple loop that will get the value of each column and add it into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the first ResultSet and Store them in a `HashMap<String , Object>`  where use column1 as the Key and the put all the remaining columns in a Bean object.

After that iterare through the second resultSet and check whether column1 exists in the HashMap or not by just doing a lookup.  if it exists, then get the Object using getValue and then compare with the resultSet2 columns.